# How do you load a local ROM with beebdroid?

Tags: rom, emulators

I downloaded beebdroid, the bbc micro emulator and its working great but i cant figure out how to load a rom other than the ones it lists as being online.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, sorry. We open-sourced it so that people would get involved and make these sorts of enhancements. So far, we've had precisely zero contributions back. Wanna be our first? :-)

Comment: I might be interested.  How much work would you foresee, roughly, to add local ROM loading support?

Comment: Go take a look at the code on github, and see what you think. Probably not a massive task.